# SimplexSolver, binary or semi-continuous variables

Tags: java, math, optimization, apache-commons, simplex

In my long search for a pure JAVA simplex solver I have come across the [SimplexSolver](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/optim/linear/SimplexSolver.html) from Apache Commons Math 3.3 API.

Now I have figured out the basics, but what I want to know is, if this simplex solver is able to solve problems that include binary(may, or may not have been used in the solution) or [semi-continuous](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/semi-cont.htm) variables.

I have spent a couple of days on google searching for a solution that uses Simplex and that I can use in JAVA without any JNIs, but sadly this is as far as I've gotten.

The problem I'm trying to solve: 
**X needs to be >= 100 and <= 10000 OR 0**. Which is what semi-continuous variables are for...

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: The Apache Simplex solver is for pure Linear Programming (LP) problems only. You are looking for a Mixed Integer Programming (MIP) solver.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. I figured it was something like that. I have seen the simplex algorithm extended to include binary and semi-continuous variables (in LpSolve I think), but maybe it was done in a different way or I have misunderstood. 

Do you by any chances know a MIP solver that is pure java? I had no luck on google. Everything is implemented on native.

Comment: Sorry. They may exist but I don't know of any MIP solver in pure Java.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Simplex solver is for pure Linear Programming (LP) problems only. You are looking for a Mixed Integer Programming (MIP) solver. – Erwin Kalvelagen